# SQL query Iterate through tables and multiply each column row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stuck on the best way to iterate through the below SQL tables and perform multiplication of the values in Table 1 against prices in table 2 where string 1 and string 2 match in SQL server, then insert the results into a results table

This data is part of a C# windows app I am developing while learning. Usually, I would just read the tables into a dataset, multiply both tables where needed and add the results to another dataset to use.

This seems a long-winded way of doing this as the table data values and price matrix is 64 * 1600 when potentially I can use a SQL server's resources and return the results more rapidly than using the power on a user's laptop.

**Table 1**

| string 1 | string 2 | value 1 | value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| red | red | 200 | 300 |
| blue | blue | 200 | 300 |
| yellow | yellow | 200 | 300 |
| green | green | 200 | 300 |
| purple | purple | 200 | 300 |

**Table 2**

| string 1 | string 2 | price 1 | price 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| red | red | 11.99 | 16.99 |
| blue | blue | 12.99 | 17.99 |
| yellow | yellow | 13.99 | 18.99 |
| green | green | 14.99 | 19.99 |
| purple | purple | 15.99 | 20.99 |

**results**

| string 1 | string 2 | tCost 1 | tCost 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxxxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxxx |
| xxxxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxxx |
| xxxxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxxx |
| xxxxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxxx |
| xxxxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxxx |

I have made this starter code but need to iterate through all the value/price columns in each table, similar to a for loop in C.

```
SELECT 
ISNULL((table1.[value 1] * table2.[price 1),'0') as [tCost 1]
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.[string 1] = table2.[string 1] 
and table1.[string 2] = table2.[string 2]
```

Comment: Do you only store xxxxxx in your tables? Sample data that makes sense would make this problems easier to understand. Also add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: I suggest tagging sql-server because many people wouldn't even read the question if you haven't tagged the sql you are using. Also, I don't really understand your question. Are you trying to multiply through Sql or are you trying to do it with C#. If the second is true, then tag C#. Whether you are trying to do it with sql or c#, you need to give us some code that you have tried, so we can direct you towards the answer or at least have something to copy-paste and then try to help you.

Comment: If you have a record in Table1 with no corresponding record (matched on String1 & String2) in Table2 do you want anything to be output into your results table?  Similarly if you have a Table2 record with no matching record in Table1?

Comment: Tip: you want to do a join (probably `inner`; but this depends on your answer to the above), joining on `string1` and `string2`, with your select statement returning `string1`, `string1` and your calculation; e.g. `price1 * value1 tCost1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm checking your table, and I think you can use JOIN in your query, follows a example.

```
Select
    table1.String1, table2.String2, 
    ISNULL(CAST(table1.Value1 * table2.Price1 as float),'0') as [tCost1],
    ISNULL(CAST(table1.Value2 * table2.Price2 as float),'0') as [tCost2]
from 
    table1
INNER JOIN 
    table2 ON table1.String1 = table2.String1 and table1.String2 = table2.String2
```

the result will be something like that

```
String1  String2    tCost1  tCost2
red       red        2398    5097
blue      blue       2598    3597
yellow    yellow     2798    5697
green     green      2998    5697
purple    purple     3198    6297
```

Best Regards